# Dynamic PHP combo box

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

I have a registration form on my site where the date of birth is dynamic using JavaScript, where it changes the number in the days depending on the month (i.e. 28/29 in february, 31 in January etc.).  Now the following code works fine and all.

```
for (i=1; i <= 31; i++){
     var newOption = document.createElement('option');
     newOption.innerHTML=String(i);
     newOption.setAttribute('value',i);
     document.getElementById('DayOfBirth').appendChild(newOption);
}
```

But how do I implement it to support PHP data which is laid out like so

```
<select name="dobDay">
     <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, htmlentities($row_LoggedOnUser['dobDay'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>1</option>
     <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, htmlentities($row_LoggedOnUser['dobDay'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, It's not clear what the problem is or what you're trying to achieve. Please give more details.

Comment: Well the first set of code (written in JavaScript) is too add a list of values to a combo box.  The second set of code is what is used to select the value that is stored on the SQL server.  How do I implement the first box of code to accomodate the second block.